# SharePoint Online List Search Bar

Tags: list, sharepoint-online

[image]

The search bar in SharePoint Online does not fetch results.

Solution I have tried

Solution 1: Reindex List

- List Settings
- Advanced Settings
- Reindex List

Is there any other way to troubleshoot the search bar.

Comment: Are you expecting specific list results?

Comment: Whether all results not searchable in this site collection? Or issue occurs in one list or library? How do you search? Please provide specific search query. Go to site settings to check result source and query rule for this site collection.